# Write SQL code in common english for non-programmers to understand

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a known standard for writing **SQL logic to common English** for non-programmers to understand? The Monthly Reports I'm generating need to be verified by the client and I don't think I have the balls to shove SQL down his richie rich throat. :)

For example, this:

```
SELECT cust.*
FROM sl_customers cust
LEFT JOIN sl_orders orders ON cust.id = orders.customer_id
WHERE 
    DATE_FORMAT(orders.delivery_date, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '2014-08-01' AND '2014-08-31'
    AND DATE_FORMAT(cust.created, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '2014-08-01' AND '2014-08-31'
    AND orders.status != 'cancelled'
    AND cust.entry = 'New User'
    AND cust.infosrc IN ('Ads - Newspaper', 'Ads - TV', 'Ads - Radio', 'Internet - Social Network')
```

Comment: just write : This report shows all new users who have placed order in the last month and they joined as well in the last month. The report also validates the information source of the user to be one of the following : Ads in newspaper , Ads in radio , Social Network.

Comment: Apparently this is not a new questions... look at this document from the 1980's. http://ijcai.org/Past%20Proceedings/IJCAI-83-VOL-2/PDF/014.pdf

Comment: SQL is already rather verbose so just putting in decent aliases will go a long way to making it readable by non-coders as well. I mean "SELECT stuff FROM somewhere JOIN something" is already english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a mostly line-by-line translation:

```
SELECT cust.*
```

Get the customer information…

```
FROM sl_customers cust
LEFT JOIN sl_orders orders ON cust.id = orders.customer_id
```

…for every order (and the customer associated with the order's customer ID),…

```
WHERE 
    DATE_FORMAT(orders.delivery_date, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '2014-08-01' AND '2014-08-31'
```

…where the order's delivery date is between August 1st and 31st…

(Aside: This part, and the following one, could be written more simply in SQL as `orders.delivery_date BETWEEN '2014-08-01' AND '2014-08-31'`. You don't need the `DATE_FORMAT()` here.)

```
    AND DATE_FORMAT(cust.created, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '2014-08-01' AND '2014-08-31'
```

…and the customer's created date is between August 1st and 31st…

```
    AND orders.status != 'cancelled'
```

…and the order's status is not "cancelled"…

```
    AND cust.entry = 'New User'
```

…and the customer's entry is "New User" (whatever that is?)…

```
    AND cust.infosrc IN ('Ads - Newspaper', 'Ads - TV', 'Ads - Radio', 'Internet - Social Network')
```

…and the customer's infosrc is "Ads - Newspaper", "Ads - TV", "Ads - Radio", or "Internet - Social Network".

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a standard, but if I were trying to explain this to a non-SQL speaker, I'd say something like:

> This gives me all the new customers created during August 
>   who have active (non-cancelled) orders
>   delivered during August and who came from
>   newspaper, TV, or radio ads, or through social media

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as "SQL logic to common English". Basically, SQL is for developers to understand, not for executives who have no development skills. The closest you can get (professionally) is designing a diagram, if you have some BA skills such as a Data Flow Model Diagram, a Data Flow Diagram or a Database Diagram. If you don't, then simply put it in plain English...

> Gets "new" customers who came from "Ads, Social Network, etc" that have an "active order" to be delivered in August

As a aside note, consider using an `INNER JOIN` instead

Comment: Actually the intention behind SQL _was_ to create a query language that could (also) be understood by non-programmers. The acronym SQL stems originally from "*Structured **English** Query Language*"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm not quite sure what's your point here. That might had been the intention and that might had been the original meaning of the acronym when it was created by IBM when I wasn't even born, but it is NOT anymore. It actually stands for `Structured Query Language` now. Furthermore, it is (by far) NOT a language to be understood by everyone, not in year 2014

Comment: It was more meant as a "fun fact" - I do agree that the initial aim that the language should also be suitable for more business oriented users does not hold true any longer (if it ever did at all)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yup, that was probably in the era when one needed to have a master's degree in computers science to use a "mainframe" lol